# HSQL column name contains #

Tags: java, junit, db2, hsqldb

I'm working on using JUnit to test an application.  I've decided to use HSQL to create an in memory database at run time.  This works fine when I am mocking an Oracle database.  However, when I try to mock our existing DB2 database, I run into an issue.  One of the columns we use has the # symbol in the column name (i.e. "Person#").  HSQL can not interpret this character and will throw a hard error when trying to load the schema.

I've tried to put HSQL in DB2 mode and still no luck.  Is it possible to use a # symbol in HSQL or any other in memory database?  Unfortunately changing the column name would be too much work for simply test coverage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to enclose the column name in double quotes:

```
CREATE TABLE foo 
(
  "PERSON#"   VARCHAR(10)
)
```

unfortunately you will then need to **always** use double quotes when accessing that column

Comment: Thanks!  That did the trick.  It's too bad that I'm going to have to always use double quotes to access the field.  But I think DB2 will also accept the quotes so we'll make the necessary changes to the DAO layer to make our application more database independent.

Comment: The ´#´ character is a non-standard character according to the SQL standard. DB2 is graceful enough to allow it, other DBMS might also have a problem with that character, so if you plan to port this application to another DBMS you might well consider to remove the `#` character alltogether